# why freader module in python 3.6 show error even i installed freader package?

Tags: python

```html
from nltk.util import ngrams
from freader import FileReader

class Preprocessor:
  def __init__(self, filePath, ngrams=1):
    self.reader = FileReader(filePath)
    self.ngrams = ngrams
    self.sentences = [ ]
    self.processed = [ ]
    self.paragraphStructure = { }
    self.sCount = 0
    self.pCount = 0

  def parse(self):
    self.reader.read( self.process )
    return self
```

I found that freader version is 0.0.0.Is it deprecated or not?
[Package installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx0PH.png)
[Showed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htBJh.png)

Comment: There is no package named `freader`: https://pypi.org/search/?q=freader

Comment: ok thanks i fount that error